# How do I remove unused dependencies from react-scripts?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-scripts

I'm trying to removed dependencies like jest. Also workbox-webpack-plugin has a dependency of a dependency with google analytics with is really annoying.

Am I able to remove these things somehow without ejecting?

Comment: Probably not, really.

Comment: What package manager do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Using commands below -

```
npm uninstall <package_name> <br>
npm uninstall --save <package_name>
```

If you want to know in more detail visit [this link](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-remove-unused-dependencies-in-react)

Comment: eg. npm uninstall react-router-dom